# Open form in separate thread, and keep it on top of other windows in the application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Yet another question about this issue. Trust that I have investigated thoroughly, but still not found a solution, which fits my application.

**Introduction:**
My application consists of a main form and a couple of forms, which are shown as modal when needed.
Then I have a "Screen dump" form, which is a small form with a button. When this is pressed a screen dump is made of the screen.

All of the above forms are displayed by pressing corresponding buttons on the main form.

**What I want:**
When displayed, the screen dump form should always be on top of all other windows of my application (also windows shown with ShowModal()). It is acceptable if this automatically means on top of all other programs as well.

**What I have tried:**
I am pretty sure I have to open the form in a separate thread, in order to keep it operatable even when other forms are shown modal.
This I have tried as follows:

```
private void btnScreenDump_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }

private void ThreadProc()
        {
            using (FormScreenDump frmScreenDump1 = new FormScreenDump())
            {
                frmScreenDump1.TopMost = true;                  
                Application.Run(frmScreenDump1);
            }                
        }
```

**What is the problem/question?**
Issue 1:
The form frmScreenDump1 is not topmost at all. Whenever any other forms are clicked in my application the form frmScreenDump1 goes behind the application.
Why is the form not topmost when frmScreenDump1.TopMost = true;, and what must I change to get this behavior?

Issue 2:
I want the form frmScreenDump1 to close automatically whenever the main form is closed. How should I do this when this form is run on a separate thread?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't open forms in other threads. All UI related code (and objects) ***must*** be on the UI thread, or unexpected things may happen. This is probably why your form is not top-most even though you've set it to be.

If you want to show other forms as modal while leaving this form active, then *don't show the other forms as modal*. Instead have every new form change the parent/owner form's `Enabled` property whenever it opens/closes.

Alternatively, put your form in a separate application and start it as a new process from your main app.

Comment: The screen dump function should be able to also take screen dumps of e.g. message boxes, which always appear modal.

Comment: @JohnSaps : Then you'd better put `FormScreenDump` in another process (or alternatively make a custom message box-like form). Though you can show Windows's message boxes in a secondary thread if you want.

Comment: When you suggest to put FormScreenDump in another process, do you mean to create a completely separate application for this small function, and then start the .exe from my main application?

Comment: @JohnSaps : Yes. Even if it's small, it's the best for what you need it for.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. How should I go about accepting this as answer??

Comment: @JohnSaps : Glad I could help! If you by your question meant _"Should I accept this?"_, then yes: You should accept it if my suggestion(s) solved your problem.

Comment: @JohnSaps : I added one of the (from the comments) mentioned alternatives to my answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

`Form.TopMost`, according to users on other TopMost-related questions, is working for all forms inside an application, but you're having two applications [Which is wrong, i misread].

So you're building a screenshot function that is supposed to work if a form is opened as a dialog. That's why the thread and the extra application for the new form. I had the same requirement once and i solved it by having my screenshot function not react to it's own click event, but instead i used a mousehook to track when the user clicks at the place where the button is located. Warning: mouse-hooks are leading to heavy lagging when starting the app in VS debug mode.

Comment: I only have one application, but more than one thread. The screen dump function is just a separate form, which I am starting in a separate thread.

Comment: Guess i misread that. Sorry! Did you try Form.ShowDialog instead of Application.Run?

Comment: `mouse-hooks are leading to heavy lagging when starting the app in VS debug mode` - I've never had such a problem before... Are you sure the code you've used is correct?

Comment: Hey @VisualVincent. Well, it works like intended and when i searched for the reasons, i found out that this seemed to be normal, accordings to others. Did you also use the callback method with `SetWindowsHookEx` and `CallNextHookEx`? Would be pretty cool to avoid that behaviour.

Comment: @Otterprinz : I did. For what are you using your hook(s), and how do you notice this _heavy lag_?

Comment: Though I am raising events from my mouse hook, which might be enough of a slow down so that lag doesn't occur (since it likely occurs because the callback is called extremely often when moving the mouse). -- My implementation (in VB.NET, but a compiled DLL can be found under "Releases"): https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper

Comment: Hey @VisualVincent. Thank you a lot for taking the time! I tried your implementation. I created a form-project in c# and added the project. I called `var hook = new InputHelperLib.InputHelper.Hooks.MouseHook();` in Program cs. and set a breakpoint that is reached when i click a button on the form. When the breakpoint is reached, 5 seconds of heavy lag happen.

Comment: Ah, okay I see what you mean now. I wouldn't call it _heavy_ lagging, but it's definitely lagging. To me it's not that much, and as it only happens when you hit a breakpoint (probably because VS is working with interrupting the code) I don't find it very bothering.

Comment: The hook doesn't work anymore after that, so I think it gets disposed either by VS or the OS for not working properly.

Comment: Hey @VisualVincent. I must admit that i had hoped to find a way to do hooks without the lagging. Anyway, thanks once more for taking the time to check it!